# How to handle free and paid orders with post processing?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm going around in circles trying to use [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal_commerce) to make an ecommerce site where some orders cost money and some don't (because some users have coupons that make products free).

I've set up the Checkout process as seen in the screenshot below and have created a rule as such

- Rules Event: Process checkout pane
- Rules Conditions: Price comparison (commerce
  order = $0)
- Rules Actions:

  - Change pane properties (disable billing
    information, off-site payment redirect, Payment)
  - Update the order state to (pending/complete)

[image: Checkout settings]

With this setup when the user goes through without a coupon it all works fine. When the user uses a coupon to get the price to zero on the Checkout page the user presses the <kbd>Continue to next step</kbd> button and goes to an empty Review page (the panes have been set to disabled so there is nothing to see) and they can't progress any further.

Pressing the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button on that page just bounces them back to the same page. If they press <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and go back to the shopping cart, then on through checkout and press "Continue to next step" again (the coupon has been remembered and the total is still $0) then get sent to the Checkout Complete page and `hook_commerce_checkout_complete($order)` is called.

I've tried adding extra actions to the rule, to complete the checkout or change the order status, but they have strange side effects like going to the Review page anyway, or calling that hook twice.

Can anyone help me set up the checkout and rules so that a free order goes straight to complete from the checkout page, whilst still maintaining the normal path for orders that require payments?

Comment: I believe this is a known bug in commerce discount (the integrating part of commerce coupons). Try running the latest development version

Answer (score 0):

You would be better to implement a custom payment method that can be active when the order has a 0 balance.

If the order has payment required, use the standard payment method.
If the order has no payment required, complete checkout.

e.g: https://drupal.org/project/commerce_no_payment

Comment: I'm already using that module (actually the Payment module that replaces no_payment) but I don't want the user to have to choose the "No payment" option from a radio button list as that setup directs so I want to skip right over those panes.

Comment: Just make the other payment method not available (in payment method rules configuration) then only one payment method will be active.

Comment: I have two rules to turn on credit card payments and turn off no_payment according to the order total. But when only one payment method is active the user still has to pick it from the list.